# initializing vector of char * does crazy things to my computer

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to solve this puzzle: http://www.puzzleup.com/2015/puzzle/?13

to do that, I want to calculate all the possible codes and pass them in a vector

> You will produce a set of 7-letter codes using the the letters A, B,
>   C, D, E, F and G

So I tried to create vector of char arrays. The code is shared below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

char letters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};

char * tempArr;
char * pastArr;


std::vector<char * > deneme;
char s1[] = {'a', 'b'};
char s2[] = {'c', 'd'};

void calculateAllPossibilities(int depth, int lastDepth)
{
    //depth 1 den baþlayacak
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(letters); i++ )
    {
        //

        if ( depth != 1 && depth != lastDepth )
        {
            //
            tempArr = new char[depth];
            for( int j = 0; j < depth-1; j++ )
            {
                //
                *tempArr = pastArr[j];
                tempArr++;
            }
            *tempArr = letters[i];
            for( int x = 0; x < depth; x++ )
            {
                //
                std::cout << tempArr[x] << ",";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            delete pastArr;
            pastArr = new char[depth];
            for( int k = 0; k < depth; k++ )
            {
                //
                *pastArr = tempArr[k];
                pastArr++;
            }
            delete tempArr;
            calculateAllPossibilities(depth + 1, lastDepth );
        }
        else if( depth == lastDepth )
        {
            //
            tempArr = new char[depth];
            for( int k = 0; k < depth - 1; k++ )
            {
                //
                *tempArr = pastArr[k];
                tempArr++;
            }
            *tempArr = letters[i];
            for( int x = 0; x < depth; x++ )
            {
                //
                std::cout << tempArr[x] << ",";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            deneme.push_back(tempArr);
            delete tempArr;
        }
        else if( depth == 1 )
        {
            //
            pastArr = new char[depth];
            *pastArr = letters[i];
            std::cout << pastArr[0] << std::endl;
            delete tempArr;
            calculateAllPossibilities(depth + 1, lastDepth );
        }

    }
}

int main()
{

    calculateAllPossibilities(1,7);

    std::cout << deneme[0][2];

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I try to cout the values of deneme vector without using cout in functions, it gives me different thing in each compilation. Like those: ":", "_", "X", "2" :)

However, then I added couts to function and tried to see whats going on and BAM! My computer goes crazy after couts!

What am I doing wrong here? First time I encountered something like this.

Comment: What do you think this does? `delete tempArr;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to work, at all

```
        deneme.push_back(tempArr);
        delete tempArr;
```

You save a pointer to an array in the vector, and then you delete the array. Now the saved pointer points nowhere.

It would work much better with a vector of `std::string`.

Also, when you allocate an array with `tempArr = new char[depth];`, the `[]` should also be used when deleting, like `delete[] tempArray`. That lets the compiler know that you are deleting an array, and not just one char. Not that it matters too much here.

Comment: I see. So if I use std::vector<std::string> then can I pass the pointed values to the string via push_back? I am on to try. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that a `std::string` will store copies of your strings, not just a pointer to somewhere else. That way the characters will still be there when you need them.